# OpenVPN Set Up with RapidSSL Certificate

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up openvpn on my web server using a certificate I purchased through RapidSSL. All I have done so far is follow the quick start guide found [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide.html) and did some basic set up through the web interface.

RapidSSL had me put a password on my key file and now when I try and update the CA files on openvpn it gives me this error:

"[('PEM routines', 'PEM_def_callback', 'problems getting password'), ('PEM routines', 'PEM_do_header', 'bad password read')] (OpenSSL.crypto.Error)"

and this one:

"local variable 'priv_key' referenced before assignment (exceptions.UnboundLocalError)".

Obviously I need to give openvpn the password to the key file somehow but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas? I am sort of stuck at this point. So far I have only used the openvpn web interface. My website works fine otherwise. I am running apache 2.4.7 and ubuntu 14.04 on the server.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the password from the key file with

```
openssl rsa -in key_with_passwd.pem -out key_without_passwd.pem
```